# Rails 4.2 - Failing to stub delayed response for image with puffing billy - image not cached and new http connections are disabled

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have rspec tests and I feel there is a bug with puffing billy or maybe I am misunderstanding the use of whitelists in the settings.

Basically the test is about checking that, if a third party hosted image (on a service called Cloudinary) takes time to be downloaded by a page, then the user sees a loading spinner and after the image is finally loaded the spinner disappears and is not visible anymore.

I'm sure billy is the root cause as

- if I don't use puffing billy (by removing billy: true) to stub/fake a 10 seconds response delay for the third party image, as you might guess, I see the image (using save_and_open_page to make sure) too soon and my test can't be implemented.
- if I use billy by using billy: true, then the image NEVER appears (checked it by save_and_open_page) and the spinner keeps turning as the actual stubbed image never shows up , it's like it was "blocked" by puffing billy... also making the test not doable :(

**Puffing billy settings**

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
    # we must force the value of the capybara server port. We have to do that because puffing-billy
    # saves everything locally for a specific host and port. But, capybara starts your rack application
    # on a new port each time you run your tests. The consequence is puffing-billy
    # is not able to reuse the created cache files and tries to do all the API call again.
    # source - kevin.disneur.me/archives/2015-03-05-end-to-end-tests-in-javascript.html
    config.server_port = 60001
    # source: comments in coderwall.com/p/jsutlq, enable to load save_and_open page with css and js
    config.asset_host  = 'http://localhost:3000'
  end

require 'billy/capybara/rspec'
Billy.configure do |c|
  c.cache = true
  c.cache_request_headers = false
  c.persist_cache = true  
  c.non_successful_cache_disabled = true
  c.non_successful_error_level = :warn
  c.whitelist = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'https://res.cloudinary.com'] 
  c.ignore_cache_port = true
  c.cache_path = "spec/support/http_cache/billy/"  
  # Only set non_whitelisted_requests_disabled **temporarily**
  # to false when first recording a 3rd party interaction. After
  # the recording has been stored to cache_path, then set
  # non_whitelisted_requests_disabled back to true.
  c.non_whitelisted_requests_disabled = true  
end
```

**The rspec test:**

```
context "non signed in visitor", js: true, billy: true do

describe "Spinner shows while waiting then disappears" do               
  it "should work" doproxy.stub("https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg").and_return(
   Proc.new { |params, headers, body|
     sleep 10
    {code: 200}
 }
   )

   visit actual_deal_page_path(deal)

# detect spinner
expect(page).to have_css('div#fullPageLoadingSpinner', visible: :visible)                   
# check subsequent image elements not yet visible               
expect(page).to have_no_css("img[src*='https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg']")

 # then after 15 seconds, the cloudinary image finally is loaded and
 # the spinner disappears
sleep 15     
expect(page).to have_css('div#fullPageLoadingSpinner', visible: :hidden)                    
expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg']")
     end                    
  end           
end
```

**The image in the view**

```
<section  
    id="introImg"    
    <img      src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg" class="cld-responsive deal-page-bckdImgCover"
  </section>
```

I have tried different variations on the settings, tried also to change https//res.cloudinary to res.cloudinary.com...nothing works

Finally, I think it matters, I keep seeing in **my tests logs**:

```
puffing-billy: CACHE KEY for 'https://res.cloudinary.com:443/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg' is 'get_res.cloudinary.com_2c4fefdac8978387ee341535c534e21e2588ed76'
puffing-billy: Connection to https://res.cloudinary.com:443/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg not cached and new http connections are disabled
puffing-billy: CACHE KEY for 'https://res.cloudinary.com:443/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg' is 'get_res.cloudinary.com_2c4fefdac8978387ee341535c534e21e2588ed76'
puffing-billy: Connection to https://res.cloudinary.com:443/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg not cached and new http connections are disabled
puffing-billy: CACHE KEY for 'https://res.cloudinary.com:443/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg' is 'get_res.cloudinary.com_2c4fefdac8978387ee341535c534e21e2588ed76'
puffing-billy: Connection to https://res.cloudinary.com:443/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg not cached and new http connections are disabled
puffing-billy: CACHE KEY for 'https://res.cloudinary.com:443/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg' is 'get_res.cloudinary.com_2c4fefdac8978387ee341535c534e21e2588ed76'
puffing-billy: Connection to https://res.cloudinary.com:443/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg not cached and new http connections are disabled
```

On these Test logs, first I don't quite understand why there are so many lines for the same resource and second, what does this message mean "not cached and new http connections are disabled". I tried other tickets with similar sounding issues such as #104 or [#179](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy/issues/179) or, but my bug might be different...